# Positioning a div independent of the window

Tags: css, html, position

The picture you see bellow is a zoomed screenshot of a website. The line you see is about 1,000px wide. And if you zoom, the size of de website changes, except the size of the line. So the line is keeping his width and pushing the website out of proportion.

Is there a way I can style this line (it has a div around him) in a way it won't be pushing the content of my website?

So either way I'm looking for a way to make the width of my image variable (but I guess you can only do this using JS) or I look for a way to make this line immune to the zooming so it won't be pushing my website's content...

If their is anything unclear, please say so, I'll try again. I know it's not easy to get a hold on this specific case :)

[image]

Comment: I never heard of an element that was immune to zooming. Or is this with a browser that has a setting "zoom text only"?

Comment: @Truth, the problem exists in every browser (in the pictures case, it's Firefox) and I can't show you code (I would get some argues with my boss), I'm just asking if it's possible...

Comment: Remove any code your boss wouldn't want us to see and make a test case. http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/. Without a test case, your question makes little sense.

Comment: @Michiel: You are aware that when you publish the website, the code will be publicly available, for free, for anyone... right?

Comment: @Truth, yeps I know. But since the site is in development and there are financial results posted which hasn't been published yet, it's restricted... I'm working on a jsfiddle example!

Answer (score 0):

To ignore the window just do a div#wrap with fixed width and position relative, now all childs will be relative of #wrap, then you can resize the window and all divs will be relative of #wrap, to center #wrap just set margin: 0 auto;

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #wrap {
        width: 960px;
        position: relative; /* here is the magic */
        /* overflow: hidden */ /* enable here if you ilke "crop" on width */
    }
</style>
<div id="wrap">
    <!-- YOUR CODE HERE -->
</div>
```